Help me please with installing ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS and dual booting with windows 7
can some one help me, i need two OS in my computer ubuntu and windows 7

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ensure you have fastboot or hibernate disabled on your system, download your desired Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system (there are multiple 22.04 products; Server, Desktop etc) then verify ISO, write to install media (as per docs) then boot & install alongside or whatever is appropriate for your intended usage.. boot & use system.  You've tagged kernel without clue as to significance, the Desktop & Server ISOs will install different kernel stacks; but if it's not what you want, you can change that post-install.

That depends on your system. Systems can have different CPU architectures, BIOS/UEFI firmware, etc. Assuming you have a 64-bit CPU and legacy BIOS (UEFI systems boot differently), download your desired version of Ubuntu (I recommend 24.04 for stability/support or 24.10 for latest software).
Download software like Etcher or Rufus to burn the iso file you download to a USB stick. Once it completes, keep the drive in your computer and restart it. Depending on your manufacturer, you may have to push a certain key to choose boot device (your computer might show "Press F9 to select boot volume" or "Press F10 to enter BIOS Setup"). If you're unsure, look up your brand's bios key. In any case, if you have a boot menu, boot Ubuntu or USB Flash Drive. If you are in BIOS setup, look for boot order (it could be under advanced) and change USB to first boot priority. Save changes if necessary and restart to Ubuntu.
It will then prompt you to select language, keyboard, drivers, etc. If you have an NVIDIA GPU or a wifi chip, you may need to install additional drivers (click the box). When it asks you about disks, it will tell you "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" (BIOS) or "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" (UEFI). Click whichever option shows up and choose how much space to allocate to Ubuntu. I'd recommend at least 50 GB if you want to store user data on the Windows partition, or at least 100 GB if you want to store on Linux partition (software can take up a lot of space!). Select your time zone and username/password, and confirm on the review screen. It will notify you when installed, click reboot and remove USB drive. Once you reboot, you will have the GRUB menu that lets you choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Just about every computer manufactured in 2012 or later has UEFI firmware, not BIOS.

@karel Yes, but some older devices upgraded to Windows 7 (I have BIOS computers that did that). Also, I have a Windows 10 desktop that came shipped with BIOS compatibility mode on, UEFI disabled. I had to enable it. So yes, while most computers have UEFI, the fact that it's a Windows 7 means there is a chance of BIOS firmware showing up if it was on my 2015 desktop.
